# My code is not working if I called it from an external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
var list_template, albums_template, photos_template, animal_template;
var current_album = animals_data.category[0];
var current_photo = current_album.animals[0];

function showTemplate(template, data, area){
var html    = template(data);
$(area).html(html);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
var source = $("#list-template").html();
list_template = Handlebars.compile(source);

source = $("#albums-template").html();
albums_template = Handlebars.compile(source);

source = $("#photos-template").html();
photos_template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

source = $("#photo-template").html();
animal_template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    function photoClick() {
    var index = $(this).data("id");
        console.log(index);
        current_photo = current_album.animals[index];

        $(".nav-tabs .active").removeClass("active");
        $("#photos").addClass("active");

        showTemplate(animal_template,current_photo,"#content");

};
function albumClick() {
        var index = $(this).data("id");
        current_album = animals_data.category[index];

        $(".nav-tabs .active").removeClass("active");
        $("#albums").addClass("active");

        showTemplate(photos_template,current_album,"#content");

    $('.photo-thumbnail').on("click", photoClick);

    };  

    $('#home').click(function() {
        showTemplate(albums_template,animals_data,"#content");

        $(".nav-tabs .active").removeClass("active");
        $("#home").addClass("active");

        $('.album-thumbnail').on("click",albumClick);
});

$('#classList li').on("click",albumClick);

$('#home').click();
showTemplate(list_template,animals_data,"#list");
});
```

which is from an external file source. Whenever I load my HTML file, only the

```
showTemplate(list_template,animals_data,"#list");
```

works. However, if I transfer this part of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function photoClick() {
    var index = $(this).data("id");
        console.log(index);
        current_photo = current_album.animals[index];

        $(".nav-tabs .active").removeClass("active");
        $("#photos").addClass("active");

        showTemplate(animal_template,current_photo,"#content");

};
function albumClick() {
        var index = $(this).data("id");
        current_album = animals_data.category[index];

        $(".nav-tabs .active").removeClass("active");
        $("#albums").addClass("active");

        showTemplate(photos_template,current_album,"#content");

    $('.photo-thumbnail').on("click", photoClick);

    };  

    $('#home').click(function() {
        showTemplate(albums_template,animals_data,"#content");

        $(".nav-tabs .active").removeClass("active");
        $("#home").addClass("active");

        $('.album-thumbnail').on("click",albumClick);
});

$('#classList li').on("click",albumClick);

$('#home').click();
```

into my HTML file, it loads perfectly. I want to know what's causing this error and how can I fix it. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: what error you are seeing in console?

Comment: Nothing really. I am using handlebars.js to populate my document and my page is somewhat of an image gallery. The problem is there are no images being displayed the only thing being displayed is my navbar, which is created using: showTemplate(list_template,animals_data,"#list");